# rabbit-mq in Ubuntu 16.04 fails to start without clear message error

Tags: rabbitmq

I had a `rabbit-mq` service running and I suddenly see that the service is not running and that I cannot start it.

I have checked other existing questions regarding this kind of problems, and most of them point to problems in /etc/hosts configuration

The result of restart is:

```
/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart
```

`[....] Restarting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl): rabbitmq-server.serviceJob for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

```
failed!
```

And the detail in systemctl is:

```
systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service
rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mié 2018-10-03 13:07:32 CEST; 42s ago
Process: 5545 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=2)
Process: 4564 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server-wait (code=exited, status=2)
Process: 4563 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 4563 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)


systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ Messaging Server...
rabbitmq[4564]: Waiting for rabbit@edr ...
rabbitmq[4564]: pid is 4571 ...
systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
rabbitmq[4564]: Error: process_not_running
systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ Messaging Server.
systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The result of `journalctl -xe` gives not much more info.

And the file /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err shows a message truncated like this:

```
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Cookie file /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erl
tail: /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err: file truncated
```

Is there another way to find the exact error when rabbit-mq fails to start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found the detailed error in `/var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log` which says:

```
{error_logger,{{2018,10,3},{13,14,18}},“Cookie file /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only”,[]}
```

I thought it would be better to let rabbitmq create a fresh file, so the solution applied was to remove the erlang cookie file:

```
rm /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
```

After that, restarting rabbitmq makes it work again.

Answer (score 1):

```
chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie

chmod 600 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
```