# start rabbitmq-server ERROR

Tags: openstack, rabbitmq

I tried starting rabbitmq-server when installing rabbitmq on Ubuntu and I get the following Error:

```
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-08-30 18:31:15 CEST; 5s ago
    Process: 89134 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 89134 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I already tried `rm /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`, but permission was denied. Restarting doesn't work too. I would really appreciate it, if you could help me solve this problem :)

Comment: Check this out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472974/rabbit-mq-in-ubuntu-16-04-fails-to-start-without-clear-message-error

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, i already did and both of them don’t work. None of the commands are permited.